# In use numeral systems

Tags: numerals, symbol

In addition to Western and Eastern Arabic numeral symbols is there any other numeral symbols in active use nowadays? There is 460 decimal (46 numeral set) and 224 non-decimal number in Unicode, which ones are in use? (You can use BabelPad to see the numeral Unicode characters)

Knowing the answer help developers in localization too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are several systems of numeral symbols in active use; for example, Chinese numbers are in very active use.

Many of the systems are described to some extent in the Unicode Standard; start from section [15.3 Numerals](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch15.pdf#page=11) to find such info.

Comment: Thanks, In china photos I see they use Western Arabic, Is Chinese numbers are used concurrently with it? Which others numeral systems are used officially?

Comment: @PHPst The Chinese numerals are used where we would use words: 五 means "five" while 5 means "5".